# How can I include Swift documentation in a Private CocoaPod .xcframework?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcframework, docc

I have created a Swift library where I added a documentation (with /** */ or ///). This documentation works when I work on the main project. But I need to export the library in a Private CocoaPod Github repo in a .xcframework (pre-compiled). When I do it, I don't have my documentation added to the framework. Here is my code to export my project as a framework:

```
for PLATFORM in "${PLATFORM_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    export_podspec $PLATFORM
    
    #xcframework path

    FRAMEWORK_PATH=${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER_NAME}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}_$PLATFORM

    # set path for iOS simulator archive
    mkdir ${PROJECT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER_NAME}
    mkdir ${PROJECT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER_NAME}/$PLATFORM
    SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH=${PROJECT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER_NAME}/$PLATFORM/simulator.xcarchive

    # set path for iOS device archive

    IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH=${PROJECT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER_NAME}/$PLATFORM/iOS.xcarchive

    echo “Archiving ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} ${PLATFORM}”

    #  mkdir ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH}
    #  mkdir ${IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH}

    xcodebuild archive \
        -workspace '../../Project/Project.xcworkspace' \
        -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} \
        -configuration Debug \
        -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
        -archivePath ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH} \
        SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
        BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
        "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS=-D EXPORT -D ${CLIENT} -D ${PLATFORM} -D ${VERSION}"

    xcodebuild archive \
        -workspace '../../Project/Project.xcworkspace' \
        -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} \
        -configuration Release \
        -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
        -archivePath ${IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH} \
        SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
        BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
        "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS=-D EXPORT -D ${CLIENT} -D ${PLATFORM} -D ${VERSION}"

    OUTPUT_PATH=${HOME}/Desktop/${FRAMEWORK_FOLDER_NAME}/$PLATFORM
    mkdir ${OUTPUT_PATH}
    
    mv $(get_podspec_path) ${OUTPUT_PATH}

    xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
        -framework ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework \
        -framework ${IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework \
        -output ${OUTPUT_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework

    rm -rf ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH}

    rm -rf ${IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH}
done
```

Is it possible to add the document I wrote with this script ?

I tried to compile the documentation (CMD+Ctrl+Shift+D) then export the framework. But it didn't work.